# initialization from incompatible pointer type

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite, tableview

```
-(void)initializeTableData
{
    sqlite3 *db=[DatabaseTestAppDelegate getNewDBConnection];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement=nil;
    const char *sql="select * from WhereTo";
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, NULL)!=SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert1(0,@"error in preparing staement",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    else {
        while(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
            [tableData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement,1)]];
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

at `sqlite3 *db=[DatabaseTestAppDelegate getNewDBConnection];` <--- it says, DatabaseTestAppDelegate may not respond to '+getNewDbConnection'

and here is my getNewDbConnection

```
+(sqlite3 *) getNewDBConnection{
    sqlite3 *newDBconnection;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Malacca-lah.sqlite"];
    // Open the database. The database was prepared outside the application.
    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &newDBconnection) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Database Successfully Opened :)");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error in opening database :(");
    }
    return newDBconnection;
}
```

im new to XCode and also SQLite... been learning this for the past few weeks now, trying to get a hang on it... anyways, pls help me out with this problem. I understand the whole code but i dont understand why the inheritance has an issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it says that a class may not respond to a selector, it means that it can not able to find the method declaration of the selector. Have you declared the method `+(sqlite3 *)getNewDBConnection` in `DatabaseTestAppDelegate`'s header(`".h"`) file?

Comment: yes.. i did declare it... i dont think anything is wrong with the code, i think there's something wrong with the compiler... ill try reinstalling it...

Comment: @Harvin, Have you declared it correctly. You declared it with `"+"` or `"-"` symbol. That should be a `"+"` symbol.

Comment: i declared wrongly... i declared as "-" instead of "+"... thank you.
another question. There are no errors now, but there is no output. even at the console log there isnt any activity going on. i tried placing a tableView in the XIB but it crashed with the "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error. sorry for bothering you

Comment: @Harvin, On which line it throws "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error?

Comment: on this line
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
 return 1;
}

Comment: @EmptyStack, when i build and run, the compiled data just goes black... and the console log has no issues... what is it that i missed?

Comment: @Harvin, You may have missed to set the delegate

Comment: @EmptyStack, what does this mean?  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'error in preparing staement'

sorry to bother u so much. been learning and trying to do this for a week.

Comment: It means that there is some problem executing the sql. Is your database opened correctly? Is there really a table named `WhereTo` in db?

Comment: @Harvin, I mean whether the line `sqlite3 *db=[DatabaseTestAppDelegate getNewDBConnection];` returns correct value?

Comment: i dont understand regarding the DatabaseTestAppDelegate @EmptyStack. Regarding the WhereTo table, it is in SQLite. i added it into the folder under resources.